# How to get work Tweetie.js with wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tweets

I've been using [tweetie.js](https://github.com/sonnyt/Tweetie) jquery plugin several times in html projects, and i never had a problem with it. Now i'm trying to integrate it with wordpress with lack of success. I checked everything several times, but i always end up with the following error in the console:

```
 GET http://domain.com/api/tweet.php?username=&count=1&exclude_replies=false
 No input specified
```

Any ideas what's wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your username is blank. If you try this also then try the code below. it worked fine in WP

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-dnt="true" href="https://twitter.com/{TWITTER-USERNAME}" data-widget-id="{WIDGET-ID}" data-show-replies="false" data-tweet-limit="1" data-chrome="nofooter"></a>

<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Comment: Where should i paste it?

Comment: Yeah that's working but not what i need. I need a css customizable twitter feed instead of embedding twitter's iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your `api/config.php` file and replace variables with your Consumer and oAuth Keys.

```
 define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'CONSUMER_KEY_HERE');
    define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'CONSUMER_SECRET_HERE');
    define('ACCESS_TOKEN', 'ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE');
    define('ACCESS_SECRET', 'ACCESS_SECRET_HERE');
```

you can find your keys [here](https://apps.twitter.com/) after login

Comment: It's completed, i told i used tweetie for several times in html projects. I tried my config.php file in a html test file, it's working.